# Jquery form  не сробатывает

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>George</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link type="text/css" href="css/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode",
            buttons: {
      "Отправить": function() {

         $('#forma').ajaxsubmit({  url: 'mail.php', success: function() { $("#result").load("mail.php"); }, error: function() { alert('Error'); } });

      },
      "Закрыть": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
        });

        $( "#mne" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog"> 
<form action="mail.php" method="post" id="forma">
<textarea name="txt"  rows="6" style="width:100%; height:100%"></textarea>
</form>
<div id="result"> </div>
</div>

<div id="shadow"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
<div id="mne">
</div>

</div>
    <div id="info">
    <div id="name">
    Contacts...
    </div>

        <div id="contact">
        <a href="http://vk.com/egorbuhta"><img src="/img/vkontakte.png" width="60" height="60" alt="Я в Вконтакте"></a><a href="http://twitter.com/egor_buhta"><img src="img/twitter.png" width="64" height="64" alt=""></a><a href="http://gplus.to/egorbuha"><img src="img/google-plus-icon-3.png" width="64" height="64" alt=""></a>

     </div>   
</div>
    <div id="news">
    <div id="name">
    News...
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="events">
    <div id="name">
    Twits...
    </div>
    <center>
    <script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 225,
  height: 220,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#623192',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#602f91',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#edf0eb'
    }
  },
  features: {
        loop: false,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('egor_buhta').start();
</script></center>
  </div>
</div>    
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Нужно отправить  форму нажатием кнопки Отправить в окне #dialog и получить ответ в #result   на первый взгляд всё верно но браузер со мной не соглашается=((((

Answer (score 1):

Все потому что в jquery ui dialog при создании диалогового окна див на самом деле дублируется, и ваш обработчик не сработает в любом случае. Чтобы все было ок нужно обработчик повешать через событие open вашего диалогового окна.

```
open: function(){
    alert('примерно так');
},
```

Это при описании диалогового окна.